# Scala type class pattern and generic methods

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, spray-json

I'm trying to write a generic extractor for parsing json POST body using spray and spray-json.

However I'm struggling to get it working with more than one model. Here's the case statement in the service object:

```
import MyJsonProtocol._

...

def receive = {
  case Post (Routes.person.post, p: Person) => sender ! Ok(Actions.person.post(p))
  case Get  (Routes.foo.forId(x))           => sender ! Ok(x)
  case _                                    => sender ! Ok("No handler")
}
```

And here's the extractor I wrote (that works as long as there's only a JsonReader for a single model in the scope of the case statement):

```
//NB. Json.parse returns an Option[T]
object Post extends Request {
  def unapply[T:JsonReader](req: HttpRequest): Option[(String, T)] = req match {
    case HttpRequest(POST, url, _, HttpBody(_, body), _) => Json.parse[T](body.asString).map((url, _))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

However, as soon as I add a new model (and associated JsonReader) the code no longer compiles with this error:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value personFormat in object Json of type => spray.json.RootJsonFormat[com.rsslldnphy.foam.models.Person]
[error]  and value animalFormat in object Json of type => spray.json.RootJsonFormat[com.rsslldnphy.foam.models.Animal]
[error]  match expected type spray.json.JsonReader[T]
[error]     case Post (Routes.person.post, p: Person) => sender ! Ok(Actions.person.post(p))
```

The fact that the generic types of the JsonReaders are different appears to be lost. Is this type erasure? Is there a way around it to get what I want?

Here's the full, compiling code of the project so far with a comment in `ExampleService` that explains what makes it break: [github.com/rsslldnphy/foam](http://github.com/rsslldnphy/foam). Your help is appreciated, thanks.

Or if what I want isn't currently possible, can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: have you tried `case Post[Person]` ?

Comment: I get: `not found: type Post`. I don't define a class, just an object.

Comment: maybe if you want compilable code in the answer, you should provide the same in the question

Comment: I wasn't asking for compilable code, just an explanation of what you meant and why it should work! But if it will help I'll upload the entire project to github.

Comment: @KimStebel I've added a github link to the question. Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the compiler explicit instructions to make this work. As you can see below, there is no way the compiler can infere what T is supposed to be. The compiler would need to be able to dynamically look at the Json from the request and from that imply a type (which we can only dream of it doing ;))

```
def unapply[T:JsonReader](req: HttpRequest): Option[(String, T)] = (...) Json.parse[T] (...)
```

That means to make this work you have to explicitly annotate the post as shown below:

```
import MyJsonProtocol._

...

def receive = {
  case Post[Person] (Routes.person.post, p: Person) => sender ! Ok(Actions.person.post(p))
  case Get  (Routes.foo.forId(x))           => sender ! Ok(x)
  case _                                    => sender ! Ok("No handler")
}
```

and change the definition to this

```
case class Post[T: JsonReader] extends Request {
  def unapply(req: HttpRequest): Option[(String, T)] = req match {
    case HttpRequest(POST, url, _, HttpBody(_, body), _) => Json.parse[T](body.asString).map((url, _))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: `[error] /Users/russell.dunphy/Code/Personal/foam/src/main/scala/com/rsslldnphy/foam/ExampleService.scala:31: not found: type Post
[error]     case Post[Person] (Routes.person.post, p: Person) => sender ! Ok(Actions.person.post(p))`

Comment: (Also, should the compiler not be able to infer the type of T from the fact that I explicitly name it with `p: Person`? Or from the fact that the method it is passed into, `Actons.person.post`, explicitly requires a `Person` as its argument?)

Comment: No the scala inference is not that powerful and will not infere from what you return. Also unapply is a weird case -- one second working on on how to make unapply paramterized.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't compile: `[error] /Users/russell.dunphy/Code/Personal/foam/src/main/scala/com/rsslldnphy/foam/ExampleService.scala:31: class Post of type com.rsslldnphy.foam.routing.Post does not take type parameters.
[error]     case Post[Person] (Routes.person.post, p: Person) => sender ! Ok(Actions.person.post(p))`

Comment: Sorry downloaded github code and will get to compile. Five minutes

Comment: No sorry I realized the difficulty and was looking around for a blog post I found on the topic. I will look more tonight

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm completely stuck and it's annoying me!